# colcon not adding Python module built with cmake to PYTHONPATH

Tags: ros, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My package is building a Python module using SWIG and cmake. It is a pure cmake package, using the `<build_type>cmake</build_type>` tag in package.xml. The build succeeds, and the `PATH` and `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` are updated, but `PYTHONPATH` is not. I can see the Python package installed to `install/<package_dir>/lib/python3/dist-packages`, so I know the Python package is being installed properly. `--merge-install` also correctly installs the package but does not update `PYTHONPATH`. The same package works properly with `catkin_make_isolated`.

Why is colcon not finding the Python package?

colcon-core version 0.7.1
colcon-cmake version 0.2.26

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394564/colcon-not-adding-python-module-built-with-cmake-to-pythonpath/) by [johnw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2548/johnw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2022-01-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-19**:
Hi @johnw Just an observation the question’s title doesn’t connect well with the tags and actual question. This may limit the number of people that review the question

**Comment by [johnw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2548/johnw/) on 2022-01-20**:
@osilva apparently the title got borked, I've fixed it.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-20**:
that makes so much sense @johnw. Thank you for updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out we had already solved this problem in a different project. See https://github.com/tesseract-robotics/tesseract_python/tree/master/tesseract_python for an example.

The solution is to use colcon hooks to update `PYTHONPATH`.

First, add the following to CMakeLists.txt:

```
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/share/ament_index/resource_index/packages/${PROJECT_NAME} "")
  install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/share/ament_index/resource_index/packages/${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION share/ament_index/resource_index/packages)
  file(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/share/${PROJECT_NAME}/hook/ament_prefix_path.dsv "prepend-non-duplicate;AMENT_PREFIX_PATH;")
  install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/share/${PROJECT_NAME}/hook/ament_prefix_path.dsv DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/hook)

if (${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR} LESS 3)
  file(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/share/${PROJECT_NAME}/hook/python_path.dsv "prepend-non-duplicate;PYTHONPATH;lib/python2.7/dist-packages")
  install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/share/${PROJECT_NAME}/hook/python_path.dsv DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/hook)
else()
  file(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/share/${PROJECT_NAME}/hook/python_path.dsv "prepend-non-duplicate;PYTHONPATH;lib/python3/dist-packages")
  install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/share/${PROJECT_NAME}/hook/python_path.dsv DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/hook)
endif()
```

This assumes that `PROJECT_NAME` exactly matches the ROS package name. See https://github.com/tesseract-robotics/tesseract_python/blob/8d9db169c63c2b238c6fe8ea06042983cdc51a4a/tesseract_python/CMakeLists.txt#L155 for an example.

Then create a `colcon.pkg` file with the following contents, replacing `<PROJECT_NAME>` with the name of the package. It must match the CMakeLists `PROJECT_NAME` exactly.

```
{
    "hooks": ["share/<PROJECT_NAME>/hook/ament_prefix_path.dsv", "share/<PROJECT_NAME>/hook/python_path.dsv"]
}
```

Once the hook is created, the PYTHONPATH should be updated when the colcon setup scripts are sourced.

---

Originally posted by [johnw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2548/johnw/) with karma: 33 on 2022-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1